# Google Consumer Surveys Publisher Data Reporting

Tags: google-surveys

I am asking this questions on stack overflow as requested to from a reply to this question on GitHub here: https://github.com/google/consumer-surveys/issues/4#issuecomment-208547294

We have 30+ sites that have consumer survey's running and was excited about this api becoming public so I could pull performance data about our sites. However, after reviewing everything I see that it is currently setup to only pull results of individual surveys.

Will there be updates to be able to pull publisher stats with this api?

Answer (score 1):

I work on the Google Consumer Surveys API -- the current version of the API does not offer the ability to pull publisher stats & there are no plans to add this functionality at this time.  Your request has been noted and if we have enough demand for this feature we'll consider it in the future.